# Find '~XX~' within a string with specific values

Tags: regex, vbscript, asp-classic

I have classic ASP written in VBScript.  I have a record pulled from SQL Server and the data is a string. In this string, I need to find text enclosed in `~12345~` and I need to replace with very specific text. Example `1` would be replaced with `M`, `2` would be replaced with `A`.  I then need to display this on the web page. We don't know how many items will be enclosed with `~`.

Example Data:

```
Group Pref: (To be paid through WIT)
~2.5~ % Quarterly Rebate - Standard Commercial Water Heaters
```

Display on webpage after:

```
Group Pref: (To be paid through WIT)
~A.H~ % Quarterly Rebate - Standard Commercial Water Heaters
```

I tried this following, but there are two many cases and this would be unrealistic to maintain.  I does replace the text and display correctly.

```vb
dim strSearchThis
strSearchThis =(rsResults("PREF"))
set re = New RegExp

with re
    .global = true
    .pattern = "~[^>]*~"
    strSearchThis = .replace(strSearchThis, "X")
end with
```

I am also trying this code, I can find the text contained between each ~ ~, but when displayed its the information between the ~ ~ is not changed:

```
dim strSearchThis
strSearchThis =(rsResults("PREF"))

Set FolioPrefData = New RegExp
FolioPrefData.Pattern = "~[^>]*~"
FolioPrefData.Global = True 
FolioPrefData.IgnoreCase = True

'will contain all found instances of ~ ~'
set colmatches = FolioPrefData.Execute(strSearchThis)

Dim itemLength, found

For Each objMatch in colMatches
    Select Case found
        Case "~"
        'ignore - doing nothing'
         Case "1"
         found = replace(strSearchThis, "M")

    End Select
Next
response.write(strSearchThis)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without using Regular Expressions, just checking the individual characters and writing a function that handles the different cases you have. The following function finds your delimited text and loops through all characters, calling the `ReplaceCharacter` function defined further down:

```
Function FixString(p_sSearchString) As String
    Dim iStartIndex
    Dim iEndIndex
    Dim iIndex
    Dim sReplaceString
    Dim sReturnString

    sReturnString = p_sSearchString

    ' Locate start ~
    iStartIndex = InStr(sReturnString, "~")

    Do While iStartIndex > 0

        ' Look for end ~
        iEndIndex = InStr(iStartIndex + 1, sReturnString, "~")

        If iEndIndex > 0 Then

            sReplaceString = ""

            ' Loop htrough all charatcers
            For iIndex = iStartIndex + 1 To iEndIndex - 1
                sReplaceString = sReplaceString & ReplaceCharacter(Mid(sReturnString, iIndex, 1))
            Next

            ' Replace string
            sReturnString = Left(sReturnString, iStartIndex) & sReplaceString & Mid(sReturnString, iEndIndex)

            ' Locate next ~
            iStartIndex = InStr(iEndIndex + 1, sReturnString, "~")

        Else
            ' End couldn't be found, exit
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop

    FixString = sReturnString

End Function
```

This is the function where you will enter the different character substitutions you might have:

```
Function ReplaceCharacter(p_sCharacter) As String
    Select Case p_sCharacter
        Case "1"
            ReplaceCharacter = "M"
        Case "2"
            ReplaceCharacter = "A"
        Case Else
            ReplaceCharacter = p_sCharacter
    End Select

End Function
```

You can use this in your existing code:

```
response.write(FixString(strSearchThis))
```

Comment: Thanks, when I tested it with this code it works for the first instance of text enclosed with ~ ~, but it doesn't work on the rest.  Gonna try some stuff

Individual Pref: (To be paid directly to the distributor by AOS as part of their VIP program)
Water Heaters - Negotiated individually
~MS~ % Quarterly Rebate - Tankless Water Heaters
~10~ % Quarterly Rebate - Pump and Expansion Tanks 56456

Group Pref: (To be paid through WIT)
~2.5~ % Quarterly Rebate - Standard Commercial Water Heaters

Comment: Added loop to handle multiple instances

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Split` and `Join` method...

```vb
Const SEPARATOR = "~"

Dim deconstructString, myOutputString
Dim arrayPointer

deconstructString = Split(myInputString, SEPARATOR)

For arrayPointer = 0 To UBound(deconstructString)
    If IsNumeric(deconstructString(arrayPointer)) Then
        'Do whatever you need to with your value...
    End If
Next 'arrayPointer

myOutputString = Join(deconstructString, "")
```

This does rely, obviously, on breaking a string apart and rejoining it, so there is a sleight overhead on string mutability issues.